# Get Request blocking another request

Tags: javascript, express

app.route('/clientes')
       .get(verificaAutenticacao, controller.listaClientes, controller.listaRegionais);

When I do this only 1 controller is called what is wrong?

Comment: could you give more context about what you are trying to do

Comment: Well, I'm using NodeJS, ExpressJS, MongoDB and Angular.

Comment: And I'm trying to do one route receive two middlewares, but when i call them just only one is called.

Comment: and theses middlewares are getting data in mongoDB and populate my page.

Comment: In `controller.listaClientes` are you calling `next()`?

Comment: Yes, but the problem was in my Service i needed to create an array and pass $resource with path to execute controller.listaRegionais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem...

I'm new in Express, Angular and mongo so after looking and search some logic i found the answer.

When I make a route.get and pass middleware I need create a new path, which refers about that function middleware.

Answer (score 0):

if what you're talking about is nodejs express and you're trying to add multiple middlewares to a route you should use the following syntax:

```
app.get('/example/b', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...')
  next()
}, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from B!')
})
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but when I did I took an error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: controller.listaClientes = function(req, res, next)
  {    


    var filtro = {};
  
    Cliente.find(filtro)       
    .exec()
    .then(
      function(listagem) {
        res.json(listagem);
      },
      function(erro) {
            console.log(erro);
            res.status(500).json(erro);
          }
    );
    
    next()

  };

Comment: so first instead of having a second callback for then just do .catch at the end: .then(function(){...}).catch(function(){..}) and second you can only do res.json only once. If you do that the res will be marked as finalised and you won't be able to set the headers again. I don't know why you're having so many middlewares but make sure you're finishing the response only once. You can find more information here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Comment: let me know if this helped, but if you do the example i showed you and also resolve the response once (at the end) and the other middlewares you just do some processing or whatever you want to do and then you call next() it should work.